# Running Header w/ Tufte Latex

Tags: header-footer, tufte

I'm trying to get a running header on the pages of a Tufte-formatted document. How does one do this? I put in information about the `\title`, `\author`, `\publisher` but this results in errors.

Any help out there?

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

%\title{Machiavelli and Pluralism}
%\author{Rod Johnson}
%\publisher{Interdisciplinary Institute}

\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214, 88, 18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Amiri}

%------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=Ahrenge}


\usepackage{pifont}

%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}



\begin{document}



\chapter{Machiavelli and Pluralism}

\ding{96} Rod Johnson, BYU

\section{Introduction}

Machiavelli’s cardinal achievement is his uncovering of an insoluble dilemma, the planting of a permanent question mark in the path of posterity. It stems from his \emph{de facto} recognition that ends equally ultimate, equally sacred, may contradict each other, that entire systems of value may come into collision without possibility of rational arbitration, and that not merely in exceptional circumstances, as a result of abnormality or accident or error—the clash of Antigone and Creon or in the story of Tristan—but (this was surely new) as part of the \href{http://www.google.com}{\textbf{normal human situation}}.\sidenote{Johnson, Rod. \emph{A Machiavellian Pluralism}. New York: NYU P, 2010.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no problems when I changed the font (I guess Amiri doesn't have small caps for headers). The "soul" package does not work well with xelatex, so disable it with the "nols" option.

I added letter spacing as recommended at the tufte-latex issues page whenever running with xelatex.

See example below.

```
\documentclass[nols,nohyper]{tufte-book}

\title{Machiavelli and Pluralism}
\author{Rod Johnson}
\publisher{Interdisciplinary Institute}

\definecolor{Ahrenge}{RGB}{214, 88, 18}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

%------------------------------

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linktocpage,urlcolor=Ahrenge}

  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
  \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
  \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{pifont}

%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}



\begin{document}

\maketitle


\chapter{Machiavelli and Pluralism}

\ding{96} Rod Johnson, BYU

\section{Introduction}

Machiavelli’s cardinal achievement is his uncovering of an insoluble dilemma, the planting of a permanent question mark in the path of posterity. It stems from his \emph{de facto} recognition that ends equally ultimate, equally sacred, may contradict each other, that entire systems of value may come into collision without possibility of rational arbitration, and that not merely in exceptional circumstances, as a result of abnormality or accident or error—the clash of Antigone and Creon or in the story of Tristan—but (this was surely new) as part of the \href{http://www.google.com}{\textbf{normal human situation}}.\sidenote{Johnson, Rod. \emph{A Machiavellian Pluralism}. New York: NYU P, 2010.}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```